# How to start hadoop in a certain version

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

We are using hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0 and we start namenode using `hadoop namenode`, how do I start the hadoop processes in either 0.20 mode or 0.23 mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install and configure these version of hadoop if you want to use them - there is no 'switch' to allow 2.0.0 (or any other hadoop version) to run in a lower version / mode.